# Where are default aliases defined in Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Playing with VM's (Amazon Linux) and I figured I wanted to add an alias 
`la = "ls -al"`

Sure, all good.  But in the process, I noticed there were no aliases defined in my home directory (e.g. `.bashrc`, et. al.) nor in `/etc/bashrc`.

And yet, when I run `alias`, I get a bunch of pre-existing aliases...

Where do they come from?

Comment: `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, etc.  Read the [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) section of the manual.  The list of aliases varies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}+' bash -x -l -i` to log to stderr every command invoked during your shell's startup with the file name and line number where it came from. Searching this log should make the relevant location clear.

Comment: this is the sort of answer I was looking for - but I don't really understand it...

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Activate_Bash.27s_Debug_Mode for a general introduction to `set -x`, which does discuss PS4.

Comment: xtrace (the behavior activated by `set -x`) is also discussed at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips; as for `-l` and `-i`, that tells the shell to behave as a *login* shell (running scripts/dotfiles intended to be invoked on the first shell created for a user's session), and an *interactive* shell (running scripts/dotfiles intended to be run on startup for shells which a user will interact with... as well as changing some other related defaults).

Answer (score 5):

```
grep alias /etc/*/*
```

says /etc/profile.d contains shell scripts with alias definitions.

Comment: Very specific to your OS. Not every distro has a `/etc/profile.d`.

Comment: (not sure why this is downvoted, though; with the question clarified to refer specifically to Amazon Linux, it's a perfectly good answer. The question is a little iffy in terms of topicality, but an answer shouldn't suffer for the question's sins).

Comment: on the one hand, I got the answer, plus the answer I needed, so I'm happy.

my only concern on the down vote is I searched before asking and couldn't find an answer (plenty of people telling people where to put aliases, none telling people where the defaults came from nor how to find out where the defaults came from...)

Comment: So, I can't speak to the downvotes, but on the other hand, I'm actually one of the folks on the close-as-off-topic vote. [SO's scope](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is limited to questions about problems "unique to software development", and interactive aliases are more of an end-user-focused utility than a development one (indeed, they're actually *turned off* by default in scripts!). Thus, in the future, [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) might be a better choice for questions where the link to development isn't entirely unambiguous.

Comment: That said, I appreciate that you've been making an effort to improve and edit your question and answer, to participate in the process, &c -- please don't take any criticism too harshly.

Comment: scope comments noted - the reason, for what it's worth, is google threw up appropriate responses from here - yep. I blame google...

Comment: That *is* one of the things that throws people off -- short explanation is that as the site has grown in popularity (and the number of sister StackExchange sites with their own scopes grew), the scope for StackOverflow has shrunk (and consensus on enforcement has shifted towards vigilance, to help keep the workload at keeping up quality of the questions we *do* keep manageable).

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. I am on AWS EC2 and `grep alias /etc/*/*` did throw up a lot of surprises. But I did get what I wanted: the setter of all `aliases`. Thanks @PaulvandenBergen

Answer (score 2):

For Amazon Linux 2 the `.bashrc` is located at: `/home/ec2-user/.bashrc`.
`ec2-user` is the default user so that might change depending on your setup.